# powerdesigner : Edit column length

Tags: powerdesigner

I imported all  entities and attributes from excel and generated Logical Diagram in PowerDesigner.
From Logical , I created Physical Diagram. But to generate sql scripts I need to update the column length for each tables.
I tried to update the column length from  Properties Grid.
But I am unable to edit/add column length. Tool is allowing me to enter the value, but it is not saving the value.

Please suggest me the solution.

Thanks,
Vasu

Comment: It works for me, both from the Model list of Columns, and the Table list of Columns... What is the edited column data types? varchar(nn)?

Comment: Can you add a snapshot of the edit screen, to make sure you are doing what I/we think?...

Comment: Hi, I got the solution. We need add the datatypes which are equivalent to sql server datatypes.